# Tweak brightness of widget in UE4

Tags: unreal-4, lighting

I would like to make an interactable monitor in Unreal Engine 4.26. I am using the default material for widgets as you can see in the image below:

[image: Unreal material]

The texture I would like to show is:

[image: Texture]

When I drive it in the widget the result is:

[image: Result]

---

As you can see the white are too bright and the darks are too washed out. I tried manipulating the emissive color value but I can't find a way to retain my original colors.
I also tried tweaking the exposure of my level, but I found that what works for my monitor doesn't work for the rest of the scene. Is there a way to change the material or exposure to avoid this behavior?